# Python unable to retain conditional formatting on data table while sending email through gmail

Tags: python, pandas, email

I have a sample data frame. This dataframe has a conditional formatting basis some rules.
I am trying to send this data table in email body (instead of attachment) through gmail but it losses it's conditional formatting during this process.

Can anyone help here, where I am going wrong ?

DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Reference': ['40%','30%'],
                   'colA': ['30% (20%)','25% (14%)'],
                   'colB': ['45% (20%)','25% (30%)'],
                   'colC': ['25% (30%)','35% (30%)']})
```

Formatted DataFrame:

```
def highlight(x, color1, color2):
    reference = x[0]
    ans = [None]
    for y in x[1:]:
        c = color1 if y < reference else color2
        ans.append(f"background-color: {c};")
    return ans

df = df.style.apply(highlight, color1='green', color2='red', axis=1)
```

[image]

Code which send email:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
import smtplib
import sys


recipients = ['abc@xyz.com'] 
emaillist = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in recipients]
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = "Information"
msg['From'] = 'abc@gmail.com'

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {0}
  </body>
</html>
""".format(df.to_html())

part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()

server.starttls()

server.login('abc@gmail.com', 'etehdnwyrfzgwwze')
server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

Comment: How do you generate the colored DataFrame in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to add the code. Edited my post